# Dynamic SQL Error with REPLACE double quotes to single quotes

Tags: sql, str-replace

I want single quotes around the string. For example: `select 'APPLE' from dual;` will display - `APPLE`.
But I want output as `APPLE`. Below select gives desire output.
`SELECT  REPLACE('"'||'APPLE'||'"','"','''') from dual;`

1st concat double quotes and then replace double quotes to single quotes.

The problem arises when I am trying to add this select in dynamic SQL.

Have tried adding quotes but no luck, please suggest. Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PORTAL AS
type ref_cursor is ref cursor;
END;

create or replace  procedure SP_REPLACE_TEST(p_cursor out PORTAL.ref_cursor)
IS
TABLENM varchar2(200);
vsql2 varchar2(200);
BEGIN
TABLENM := 'APPLE';
vsql2 := 'select REPLACE('||'''"'''||'||'||TABLENM||'||'||'''"'''||''','''||'''"'''||''','''||') from DUAL';
open p_cursor for vsql2;
END;

VARIABLE resultSet REFCURSOR;
EXEC SP_REPLACE_TEST(:resultSet);
PRINT :resultSet;
```